# Change C programs from using arrays to using linked list

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, prefix, infix-notation

I'm a beginner in C. I have written a 'infix, prefix, postfix conversion' program using arrays. But now I would like to change the program to use linked list to illustrate the stack.

Could anyone help modify this small part of the codes to use linked list so I can see the pattern and understand how it works ?
Thank you.

Here's the code for 'prefix to infix conversion'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>



char PrefixToInfix(char expression[]){

char *input,ans[50],answer[50][50],opr[3],temp[5]; //Initializing variables
char stack2[50],stack1[50],opstack[50],optemp;
int topa=-1,topops=-1,counter=0;
input=expression;



for( ;*input!= '\0';input++)
{
    if (*input==' ') input++;

    if (isalnum(*input)) //Checking for digit
    {
        temp[0]=*input;
        input++;
        if(isalnum(*input)){ //In double digit cases
            temp[1]=*input;
            temp[2]='\0';
        }
        else
        {
        temp[1]='\0';
            input--;
        }
    strcpy(answer[++topa],temp); //Push to stack
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 2)
    {
    strcpy(stack2,answer[topa--]); //Pop 2 operand from stack and put the operator in between them, with a parenthesis opening and closing it, and push it into stack
    strcpy(stack1,answer[topa--]);
    strcpy(ans,"(");
    strcat(ans," ");
    strcat(ans,stack1);
    strcat(ans," ");
    optemp=opstack[topops--];
    opr[0]=optemp;
    opr[1]='\0';
    strcat(ans,opr);
    strcat(ans," ");
    strcat(ans,stack2);
    strcat(ans," ");
    strcat(ans,")");
    strcpy(answer[++topa],ans);
    counter--;
    }
}
else
{
    opstack[++topops]=*input; //If operator found add to operator stack
    if(counter==1)counter=0;
}

}
while(topa!=0)
{
strcpy(stack2,answer[topa--]); //Pop 2 operand from stack and put the operator in between them, with a parenthesis opening and closing it, and push it into stack
strcpy(stack1,answer[topa--]);
strcpy(ans,"(");
strcat(ans," ");
strcat(ans,stack1);
strcat(ans," ");
optemp=opstack[--topops];
opr[0]=optemp;
opr[1]='\0';
strcat(ans,opr);
strcat(ans," ");
strcat(ans,stack2);
strcat(ans," ");
strcat(ans,")");
strcpy(answer[++topa],ans);
}
printf("Infix Expression: ");
printf("%s\n",answer[topa]);

}

int main(){

char exp[50];

printf("enter expression: ");
scanf(" %20[^\n]", exp);
PrefixToInfix(exp);


}
```

Comment: I don't feel like the change you're asking for is a "small part". You would need to write an appropriate struct and change large amounts of your code to work with them. Might be worth narrowing down your question a bit more to a specific part, and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe a bit of examples on how to change the codes to using linked list ? Because the problem right now is I don't know where to start. I have read about linked list but it's confusing compared to arrays.

Comment: then you should start by writing a linked list and make it work (not in context of this code, but just a small programm only for linked lists). As soon as you made this work you should have grasped the concept and may be able to modify this code. If problems arise we help out gladly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to transform the existing source code from fixed-array stack to linked-list stack. As @KamiKaze suggests, the first step will be to create a linked-list able to be manage as a stack.

**Step 1** - create the linked-list structure.

```
typedef struct sStack {
    char *value;
    struct sStack *next;
} Stack;
```

**Step 2** - add push() and pop() function to manage the linked-list as a stack.

```
Stack *pushStack(Stack *pStack, char *answer)
{
    Stack *pTemp = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    pTemp->next = pStack;
    pTemp->value = malloc(strlen(answer)+1);
    strcpy(pTemp->value,answer);
    return (pTemp);
}

Stack *popStack(Stack *pStack, char *answer)
{
    Stack *pTemp = NULL;

    if (pStack != NULL) {
        strcpy(answer,pStack->value);
        pTemp = pStack->next;
        free(pStack->value);
        free(pStack);
        return (pTemp);
    }
    // to prevent error
    strcpy(answer,"");
    return (pTemp);
}
```

**Step 3** - declare and initialize two stacks in `PrefixToInfix()`: `valStack` to store values and `opStack` to store operators.

```
char PrefixToInfix(char expression[])
{
    Stack *valStack = NULL;
    Stack *opStack = NULL;
    char sOpTmp[3];
```

**Step 4** - when add a new value or a new operator in the stack, use the function `pushStack()`

```
// to push a value
valStack = pushStack(valStack, temp);
// to push operator
sprintf(sOpTmp,"%c",*input);
opStack = pushStack(opStack,sOpTmp);
```

Instead of

```
// adding a value
strcpy(answer[++topa],temp);
// adding an operator
opstack[++topops]=*input;
```

**Step 5** - when remove a value or an operator from the stack, use the function `popStack()`

```
// to pop values
valStack = popStack(valStack, stack2);
valStack = popStack(valStack, stack1);
// to pop an operator
opStack = popStack(opStack,opr);
```

Instead of

```
// removing values
strcpy(stack2,answer[topa--]);
strcpy(stack1,answer[topa--]);
// removing an operator
optemp=opstack[topops--];
opr[0]=optemp;
opr[1]='\0';
```

**Step 6** - the while-condition checks the `valStack` pointers.

> When `valStack->next` is NULL, the `valStack->value` contains the
>   complete Infix expression.

```
while((valStack!=NULL) && (valStack->next!=NULL))
{
```

Instead of

```
while(topa!=0)
{
```

**Last Step** - display the Infix expression

> To prevent a bad return value due to `valStack == NULL`, use the `popStack()` function
>   instead of `valStack->value`.

```
valStack = popStack(valStack, ans);
printf("%s\n",ans);
```

Instead of

```
printf("%s\n",answer[topa]);
```

Comment: Although I've completed my assignment, but thank you for your help! I hope people that have similar problems find this post useful :D